# How to control color of letters in geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to print a row of letters, with a different color for each letter letter identified by both its color and letter shape, such as:

[image]

How can I do this using the ggplot package in R?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
s <- sample(x = c("g", "c", "t", "a"), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

ggplot() + geom_text(aes(seq(s), 1, color = s), label = s)
```

But I get the error

> Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: label

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through trial, error, a bit of searching I realized that label can be used as an aesthetic:

```
s <- s[1:20] ## make shorter for example
ggplot() + geom_text(aes(seq(s), 1, color = s, label = s))
```

[image]

Here is a piece of Art called 'Star Wars DNA' ([source](http://rpubs.com/dlebauer/star-wars-dna))

[image]